# what is HttpRequestMessage equivalent in .NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-web-api, httprequest, .net-4.5

in .net 4.5 I am using HttpRequestMessage

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage request, TourCreateRequest tourCreateRequest)
```

What can I use for .NET 4.0 that I can use similarly to  have access to the request headers, the body, the URL used to invoke the call, client certificates, and many other valuable properties. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HttpRequestMessage in .net 4 also.

Comment: Yes I finally managed to figure that. Added references to System.Net.Http and System.Net.Http.WebRequest. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

It can be used instead of `HttpClient` to make requests (and handle all of the other features in your post).

Comment: I am not using HttpClient. In the post action, I need to get all request details..... Was trying on how to get that.....

Comment: @jaxxbo - HttpResponseMessage and HttpRequestMessage are both used by HttpClient (whether explicitly or behind the scenes) to make the actual request. Prior to 4.5, the easiest way to do that was using HttpWebRequest. All of the data from HttpResponseMessage/HttpRequestMessage can be found in the HttpWebRequest instance.